# How i make Sound button ON and OFF

Tags: c#

I want to make 2 button. 1 of them to play music and another one to stop the music. But i make just the first one. How i make the stop music button ?

```
        private void Play()
    {
        string soundfile = @"D:\song.wav";
        var sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(soundfile);
        sound.Play();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Play();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`SoundPlayer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class you're using has a method to stop playback, just like it has Play. The problem is that you're not storing the instance of SoundPlayer that's playing, so you don't have a reference to it.

Try storing the `sound` variable as a class-level member. Then you can call it from a different method as well:

```
 private SoundPlayer _player;

 private void Play()
 {
     string soundFile = @"D:\Song.wav";
     _player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(soundFile); 
     _player.Play();
 }

 private void Stop()
 {
     if (_player != null)
     {
          _player.Stop();
     }
 }
```

This way the SoundPlayer is a shared member for all class methods. Note, though, the `!= null` check, which makes sure that calling Stop before Play won't crash.